# How to modify data in a javascript object by submitting from a text field with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web application where much like Uber where user can enter the address in origin and destination text fields and directions are shown on the webpage. I have done it far enough to display data such as coordinates, duration, distance etc. But I am doing it by entering fixed data 'New York' and 'Chicago'. Does anyone know how can i modify data by entering address through text fields and running the script so that values my request variable changes values and displays data accordingly. Here is my code:

```
<div>
      Pickup address
      <input id="address_origin" type="textbox" value="">
      <input id="submit_origin" type="button" value="Search">
</div>
<div>
      Drop off address
      <input id="address_destination" type="textbox" value="">
      <input id="submit_destination" type="button" value="Search">
</div>

   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 
  Duration: <input id="duration"></div> 
  Distance:  <input id="distance"></input>
  Origin Longitude <input id="origin_longitude"></input>
  Origin Latitude <input id="origin_latitude"></input>
  Destination Longitude <input id="destination_longitude"></input>
  Destination Latitude <input id="destination_latitude"></input>


<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   function address_to_coordinates_lat(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
  function address_to_coordinates_long(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }



var request = {
    origin: 'Chicago', 
    destination: 'New York',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };



  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
        directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

        console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address);
        console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address);


        // Display the distance:
        document.getElementById('distance').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
        // Display the duration:
        document.getElementById('duration').value =
          directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
         //Display origin latitude
        address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value =
          location;
                });     
        //Display origin longitude
        address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value =
          location;
                });

         //Display destination latitude
        address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value =
          location;
                });     
        //Display destination longitude
        address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location){
            document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value =
          location;
                });

      })
    } else {
      alert("directions request failed:" + status)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the text fields in your request to the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

```
var request = {
  origin: document.getElementById('address_origin').value, 
  destination: document.getElementById('address_destination').value,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true
  });

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: false,
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  getRoute();
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  function address_to_coordinates_lat(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function address_to_coordinates_long(address_text, callback) {
    var address = address_text;
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function getRoute() {
    var request = {
      origin: document.getElementById('address_origin').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('address_destination').value,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };



    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
          directions = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

          console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address);
          console.log(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address);


          // Display the distance:
          document.getElementById('distance').value =
            directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value + " meters";
          // Display the duration:
          document.getElementById('duration').value =
            directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";
          //Display origin latitude
          address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location) {
            document.getElementById('origin_latitude').value =
              location;
          });
          //Display origin longitude
          address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_address, function(location) {
            document.getElementById('origin_longitude').value =
              location;
          });

          //Display destination latitude
          address_to_coordinates_lat(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location) {
            document.getElementById('destination_latitude').value =
              location;
          });
          //Display destination longitude
          address_to_coordinates_long(directions.routes[0].legs[0].end_address, function(location) {
            document.getElementById('destination_longitude').value =
              location;
          });

        })
      } else {
        alert("directions request failed:" + status)
      }
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("get_route"), 'click', getRoute);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div>
  Pickup address
  <input id="address_origin" type="textbox" value="Chicago, IL">
  <input id="submit_origin" type="button" value="Search">
</div>
<div>
  Drop off address
  <input id="address_destination" type="textbox" value="New York, NY" />
  <input id="submit_destination" type="button" value="Search" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="get_route" type="button" value="Get Route" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
Duration:
<input id="duration" />Distance:
<input id="distance" />Origin Longitude
<input id="origin_longitude" />Origin Latitude
<input id="origin_latitude" />Destination Longitude
<input id="destination_longitude" />Destination Latitude
<input id="destination_latitude" />
```